# Count how many reads in a data file are in an interval from reference file. Python

Tags: python, mapping, intervals

I am trying to count the number of hits a value in one file(column) falls between an interval from another file (two columns).

I am completely stuck on how to map it.

I tried something like this:

```
for line in file1:
    if line[0]=line2[0] and line2[1]<line[1]<line2[2]:
    print line
```

I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
file 1:
elem1     39887
elem1     72111

file 2:
elem1     1     57898
elem1     57899 69887
elem2     69888 82111
```

In file1 elem1 is an element in my project. the value 39887 is the start coordinate.

In file2 elem1 is still an element in my project, but the values are start and end coordinates. File2 is only a reference file.

For every line in file2, I want to see if the "elem#"=="elem#" in file 1.  If the elem# in file1 is equal to elem# in file2, then I want to continue in this loop and see if the corresponding value in file1 is between the start and end positions in file2.

For instance, in the first line of file1, elem1==elem1 in the first line of file2.  Since they are equal, is 39887 between 1 and 57898? Yes it is, therefore count it.  I need to do this for every line in file2.

In the end, I want to see how many elements are within each group of coordinates from file2.

Comment: you should give an example of input output you expect

Comment: You still need to be more specific: 1) Is `elem1 39887 elem1 72111` one element? Is `i[0]=39887`? Is a match both numbers or only the first number?  2) For `elem1 1 57898 elem1 57899 69887 elem2 69888 82111` is `j[0]=1`? Which is `j[1]` and `j[2]`? 3) Provide a concrete example of a match.  It would also help if you formatted this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lines match up one-to-one (so you want to test whether the value on the first line of one file lies between the values on the first line of the other, second line to second line, etc), you can [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) the two files to iterate over them in step:

```
with open(...) as interval_file, open(...) as value_file:
    for value, interval in zip(interval_file, value_file):
        left, right = map(int, interval.split())
        if float(left) <= float(value) <= float(right):
            #do stuff
```

Comment: Well, they do not line up. I just want to see where each value in file1[1] falls based on the two columns in file2. Then count each hit I have for each interval.  I think I'm confusing myself, lol.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the concepts of 'files' for a second and think about the data.

You have two groups of textual data, one that is one column and one that is two columns, correct? Assume for a second you can work out separating the text in two colums, what you really have is three lists (after converting the strings to ints lets say):

```
c1 = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(100)]     
c2 = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(100)]
c3 = [random.randint(0,100) for i in range(100)]
```

If I understand, you want to count the interval hits of the data in c1 in c2 and c3, correct? Now focus on what a 'hit' is. If you have `3` in c1, and you have `[1,3,5,5,3,10]` in c2, how many hits is that? Only 3's? The interval between 1,3,5? Or the interval of 1,3,5,5,3? Or all the above.

As a simple example, with the randoms int lists above, this prints every int in c1 that occurs both in c2 and c3:

```
for i in c1:
    if i in c2 and i in c3:
        print i
```

Once you further define what a 'hit' is, this basic structure will work. Once you have the basic data and the 'hit' structure working, then go back and deal with the files. Should be easy then.

**Edit:**
*If* I understand what you are trying to do (and that is a massive *if*), this is a framework:

```
with open("file2.txt") as val_file:
    for val_line in val_file:
        val_elems=val_line.split()
        with open("file1.txt") as int_file:
            for int_line in int_file:
                int_elems=int_line.split()
                if (int_elems[0] == val_elems[0] and 
                    int_elems[1] > val_elems[1] and
                    int_elems[1] < val_elems[2]):
                        print val_line
```

Running against your sample data, the output: `elem1     1     57898`

It is not clear to me if you are trying to 1) positionally comparing the two files line by line or 2) if you are reading each line of file 2 and comparing to each and every line of file 1. The example here does the later.

Comment: Oh ok. And i can set my interval based on the column number? The file is enormous so it would not be efficient to set each range.  I guess I'm trying to store the values in a dictionary and then counting how many lines are in each range in sorted order.  Lol. it seems easier in my head, but hard in script. Thank you both for helping me

Comment: If you give an example of you data, your assumed 'hits' and the file size, maybe we can be more helpful. With what you supplied, it is kinda shooting in the dark.

Comment: Ok no problem. 


file 2:  
elem1 57
elem2 8890
elem2 9500
elem1 4566
 

file1    
elem1 1     1501
elem1 1502 4000
elem1 4000 5300
elem1 5300 7200
elem1 7201 7779
elem2  7780 8765
elem2 8766 10023
elem2 10024 12897

Comment: You may want to edit you questions with a) The example input from the two files, b) The expected output. From your list, I have no idea what you are looking for.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry for confusing you. I'm trying to wrap my head around this thing.

Comment: I've re-edited it. I hope its more clear now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your algorithm seems to imply that this is a line-by-line comparison between the two files. Your example data implies that `file 2` is longer than `file 1`. Which is it? For each line of `file2` are you checking against each and every line of `file1` or is it line by line for the two files?

Comment: File 2 is longer than File1.  File one is just a reference file with each element and the coordinates partitioned for each element.  Yes, I am checking the line in file1 one with all of file2 to find its matching element and then finding the corresponding coordinate for that element.